# System.TypeInitializationException: "The type initializer for 'System.Management.ManagementPath' threw an exception."

Tags: c#, wmi, system.management

I just started to code a Programm which detects the USB Sticks and this is my current code:

```
public enum EventType
        {
            Inserted = 2,
            Removed = 3
        }
        static void Main(string[] args){

            ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
            WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2 or EventType = 3");

            watcher.EventArrived += (s, e) =>
            {
                string driveName = e.NewEvent.Properties["DriveName"].Value.ToString();
                EventType eventType = (EventType)(Convert.ToInt16(e.NewEvent.Properties["EventType"].Value));

                string eventName = Enum.GetName(typeof(EventType), eventType);

                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}", DateTime.Now, driveName, eventName);
            };

            watcher.Query = query;
            watcher.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();


        }
```

But everytime i get this error: "System.TypeInitializationException: "The type initializer for 'System.Management.ManagementPath' threw an exception."

And i can not find a solution.
And yes i imported System.Management;
I would be happy if someone could help me.

Comment: I ran your code as-is and had no issues. I ran using VS 2019 Community with .Net Framework 4.7.2

Comment: There's probably a whole stack trace with inner exceptions, TypeInitializationException is only the top first one

Answer (score 0):

This error may be related to trimming, try to turn it off by setting `PublishTrimmed` to `false`.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  // ...
  <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
</PropertyGroup>
```